# Glassfish configuration on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm trying to add glassfish application server on Intellij IDEA but it gives an 'application server libraries not found' error.

libs not found :
[image: screen]

I've confirmed the installation path from netbeans-which seems to work with no issues, and the path given on the web console is the same

[image: web console]
what is it that i could be missing?
Edit:
The directory structure looks like this
[dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uv30.png)
i've tried both a level above and one level down-whereby i tried the bin and the domains folders

Comment: Please provide the list of files in the specified directory. Does it work if you specify the directory one level above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second glassfish from the path. You want:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1
```

Here's how my location looks in intelliJ (my glassfish is in the the C:\ directory)
[image]